# Unnest json in R

Tags: r, json

I know this is a popular topic but I just can't quite find a solution that gives me what I'm after.

JSON data:

```
{
    "team": [{
        "Team A": [
            {"episode":"shots","result":"accurate", "data":[{"x":"100","y":"40","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]},
            {"episode":"shots","result":"inaccurate", "data":[{"x":"95","y":"33","dx":"93.9","dy":"46.3"},{"x":"93","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]}
        ],
        "Team B": [
            {"episode":"shots","result":"accurate", "data":[{"x":"100","y":"40","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]},
            {"episode":"shots","result":"inaccurate", "data":[{"x":"95","y":"33","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"26.3"}]}
        ]
    }]
}
```

Final output (I've truncated but hopefully this is straight-forward enough):

```
tibble(team = c("Team A", "Team A", "Team A", "Team A"), 
       episode = c("shots","shots","shots","shots"), 
       result = c("accurate", "accurate", "inaccurate", "inaccurate"), 
       x= c(100,105,95,93), 
       etc = c("...","...","...","..."))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of `bind_rows` (to combine a list of data frames into one) and tidyr's `unnest` (to unnest your `data` column into multiple rows).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

j$team %>%
  map(1) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "team") %>%
  unnest(cols = data)
```

(The one part that might seem surprising is `map(1)`. This is necessary because each of the objects in the JSON object in the parsed data frame is itself a list; `map(1)` gets the first item in each).

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
  team   episode result     x     y     dx    dy   
  <chr>  <chr>   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 Team A shots   accurate   100   40    97.9  36.3 
2 Team A shots   accurate   105   68    95.8  25.9 
3 Team A shots   inaccurate 95    33    93.9  46.3 
4 Team A shots   inaccurate 93    68    95.8  25.9 
5 Team B shots   accurate   100   40    97.9  36.3 
6 Team B shots   accurate   105   68    95.8  25.9 
7 Team B shots   inaccurate 95    33    97.9  36.3 
8 Team B shots   inaccurate 105   68    95.8  26.3
```

---

Setup for the `j` object:

```
library(jsonlite)

j <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{
    "team": [{
        "Team A": [
            {"episode":"shots","result":"accurate", "data":[{"x":"100","y":"40","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]},
            {"episode":"shots","result":"inaccurate", "data":[{"x":"95","y":"33","dx":"93.9","dy":"46.3"},{"x":"93","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]}
        ],
        "Team B": [
            {"episode":"shots","result":"accurate", "data":[{"x":"100","y":"40","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"25.9"}]},
            {"episode":"shots","result":"inaccurate", "data":[{"x":"95","y":"33","dx":"97.9","dy":"36.3"},{"x":"105","y":"68","dx":"95.8","dy":"26.3"}]}
        ]
    }]
}
')
```

(Note that the code would be different if you provided `simplifyDataFrame = TRUE` when you parse the JSON object; so it's possible you may need a different approach).

Comment: Seconds apart, but this is neater. +1 !

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you can read your json into a single string and parse it with `jsonlite::fromJSON`

For this example I selected and copied the json from your question and did:

```r
x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(readClipboard(), collapse = "\n"))
```

Then you can extract the data frame using tidyverse functions like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

do.call(rbind, lapply(x$team, function(y) y[[1]])) %>%
  rownames_to_column("team") %>%
  unnest(cols = data) %>%
  mutate(team = gsub("\\..*$", "", team))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 7
#>   team   episode result     x     y     dx    dy   
#>   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>      <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 Team A shots   accurate   100   40    97.9  36.3 
#> 2 Team A shots   accurate   105   68    95.8  25.9 
#> 3 Team A shots   inaccurate 95    33    93.9  46.3 
#> 4 Team A shots   inaccurate 93    68    95.8  25.9 
#> 5 Team B shots   accurate   100   40    97.9  36.3 
#> 6 Team B shots   accurate   105   68    95.8  25.9 
#> 7 Team B shots   inaccurate 95    33    97.9  36.3 
#> 8 Team B shots   inaccurate 105   68    95.8  26.3
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan! I was assuming the answer would require lapply - which I'm still struggling with - so thanks for showing me a way that matches my thought process.